# Can I visually obtain an equation from this curve?

Tags: voltage, oscilloscope

While I was in the lab I was able to get the correct voltage curves on the oscilloscope, but time was short so I took a picture instead of measuring the voltage incrementally (the ultimate goal being a plot that fits the curve).

[image]

I'm specifically referring to the top curve - which is channel 2. Is there a way I can get an equation for this curve from the picture alone? The voltage and time scales are there, so I feel like it could be done, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Looks like a standard RC curve to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant

It looks like each block is 25ms and 1V for chnl2. Use an approximate rise time to calculate Tau:
rise time (20% to 80%): $$t_r \approx 1.4 \tau \approx \frac{0.22}{f_c}$$

Then use the difference in voltage from the start of the curve to the end to give you V0 for the charging equation:
  $$V(t) = V_0(1-e^{-t/ \tau}) $$

Use the discharge equation from that link to find the falling side equation. The tau for it will be different than for the rising one.

Comment: For t_r, do I use the rise time from bottom to top, or do I use the time required to traverse the interval 20% to 80%? From start to finish, the interval is about 100ms. If that is t_r, that would make tau = 100ms/1.4 = 71.43ms approximately. From start to finish, the curve rises about 1.6V, so that's my V_0. If the above is correct, then my equation for charging is V(t)=1.6(1-e^(-t/71.43ms)), correct?

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I think that tau should be the time it takes to reach 60% of it's maximum value. Is this correct? So, for the discharging equation I would have a different tau which corresponds to 60% of the minimum value?

Comment: @Lefty use the time it takes to traverse 20 to 80 percent. The reason you don't go from the beginning or end is because the end isn't well defined at all because it's asymptotic.

Comment: @Lefty I would say the 20-80% is about 3 tick marks. Each tick is 5ms so you've got a rise time of 15ms. That makes tau about 0.0107.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. Looks like 20-80%for the discharging part is about 1 tick mark, or 5ms. That makes tau about .00357 for the discharging section.

Comment: @Lefty That sounds about right to me.

Comment: Is this a good approximation of the entire curve, both rising and falling? It seems that <20% or >80% aren't defined well, so I'm not if that has an impact, or if it's negligible.

Comment: @Lefty With the lack of detail in the pictures, it's probably about as close as you'll come to finding the equation that matches your curve. You'd have to have zoomed into the curve to get a more accurate equation. With what you've got, I'd say it's pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a program called datathief http://www.datathief.org to turn your image into numbers very easily.  The curve is pretty near a rising exponential, of the form A[1-exp (t/tau)]

Even easier, you can draw a tangent to the curve at the step, and that tangent will intersect with the asymptotic value  at one time constant following the transition

Note that you have a much faster time constant on the decay than on the rise, so you have something nonlinear going on.

Update to reflect request for more info:

Given y(t)=A*exp(-t/tau)*u(t) (falling exponential), lets look at the slope of the line that is tangent to that curve at 0+

dy/dt = -(1/tau)* A*exp(-t/tau), and at t=0+, that's just = -A/tau

Now, lets derive the formula for the line that is tangent using the point-slope method.  At t=0, the line passes through y=A.  Therefore, (y-A)= -(A/tau)*(t-0), or y=A(1-t/tau)

The point where that line passes through the time axis is where y=0, which must happen at t=tau.

There will be a similar derivation for the rising exponential, but you can actually derive that as a step minus a falling exponential.

Of course, your accuracy in using this method depends on how well you can draw that tangent, but it's often a good ballpark.

Here's a Matlab example, A=1 and tau=2

```
>> tau=2;
>> time = [ 0: .2: 7];
>> plot(time, exp(-time/tau))
>> line(time, (1-time/tau),'color','r')
>> axis([0 7 0 1.25])
```

[image]

Note how the tangent passes through the time axis at t=2, which is equal to tau.

Comment: Probably just an asymmetric driver that can sink better than it can source

Comment: I'm really rusty working witch RC circuits, time constants, and such. My circuit theory prof did a poor job of teaching us and it's really coming back to haunt me - Needless to say, I don't really follow your logic with tangents and asymptotic values. Can you provide a good source to read up on this topic?

Comment: @Lefty, you mean the tangent thing??  If so, I'll try to beef up my post with a derivation

Comment: I added the math for you, @Lefty

Answer (score 0):

Load it up in a photo editor and count pixels.  Any decent photo editing software will tell you the location of the cursor in pixels.  So measure the rules in pixels, then measure the trace in pixels and interpolate.  Should be doable with a bit of work on paper or in excel.